# How to add borders to thead and tbody which are always visible in an overflowable div

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I am struggling about the following problem and have no idea how to solve it.
I have a table like this:

```css
.my-table-container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.my-table-container table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}


.my-table-container table thead tr {
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-table-container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>c1</th>
        <th>c2</th>
        <th>c3</th>
        <th>c4</th>
        <th>c5</th>
        <th>c1</th>
        <th>c2</th>
        <th>c3</th>
        <th>c4</th>
        <th>c5</th>
        <th>c1</th>
        <th>c2</th>
        <th>c3</th>
        <th>c4</th>
        <th>c5</th>
        <th>c1</th>
        <th>c2</th>
        <th>c3</th>
        <th>c4</th>
        <th>c5</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

The result is a table like this:

[image: Current Table]

For highlighting I need to add "borders" around the visible area of table head and table body.
The result should look like this:

[image]

The borders should not move when the table content is moved and are always visible.

Does anybody has an idea how to do that?

Best regards && thank you

Torben

Comment: Your problem is when you add a border all the content moves? If it's that you should place an invisible border initially (border: 1px solid transparent) then for highlighting only change the border-color property.

Comment: No my problem is, that I need the border to be visible "on top" of the table head (the green one) and another one "on top" of the table body (the orange one). When I scroll to left or right or top or down the border itself should not move.

Comment: @TorbenHa your mean like the border should stay fixed when the scrollbars are scrolled?

Comment: @ShamsadAnam  Yes, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could only figure out how to do it with JS. Also, your question says "around the visible area of *table head* and table body" but the screenshot shows just around `tbody`, not the table head.

https://jsfiddle.net/dgrogan/71bsnmfL/4

Side note: `position: sticky` doesn't work on `thead` or `tr` in Chrome. That won't be available in the stable channel until mid-2021 (https://crbug.com/702927). `position: sticky` does work on `th` though, if you want to try that.

```js
// This would be more robust with ResizeObserver
dogs.style.height = container.clientHeight + "px"
dogs.style.width = container.clientWidth + "px"
```

```css
 .my-table-container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.my-table-container table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}


.my-table-container table thead tr {
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; position: relative;">
  <div style="position:absolute; border: 4px dashed black; box-sizing: border-box; height: 100%; z-index: 1; pointer-events: none;" id=dogs></div>
  <div class="my-table-container" id=container>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>c1</th>
          <th>c2</th>
          <th>c3</th>
          <th>c4</th>
          <th>c5</th>
          <th>c1</th>
          <th>c2</th>
          <th>c3</th>
          <th>c4</th>
          <th>c5</th>
          <th>c1</th>
          <th>c2</th>
          <th>c3</th>
          <th>c4</th>
          <th>c5</th>
          <th>c1</th>
          <th>c2</th>
          <th>c3</th>
          <th>c4</th>
          <th>c5</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This is working perfectly fine for me, I have just adapted it to use two divs, one for the header, one for the body.